# Not getting an expected index from list

Tags: c#, list, collections, indexing

I have a list box that displays a collection. Initially the list box only contains a default database of two objects. The user adds new objects to the collection and it is updated in the list box.

Prior to the user adding a new object, my code works as intended.

Code for loading objects into the list box.

```
    private void FillStudentListBox()
    {
        lstStudents.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < students.Count; i++)
        {
            Student s = students[i];
            lstStudents.Items.Add(s.GetDisplayText());
        }            
    }
```

My update button code:

```
    public void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int target = Convert.ToInt16(lstStudents.SelectedIndex);
        if (target != -1)
        {
            UpdateStudentScores updateStudentScores = new UpdateStudentScores(target);
            updateStudentScores.Show();
        }
    }
```

If I click on one of the default users and then click Update, the form opens and is populated with the correct data. However if I add a new object and then click Update on the new object I get an error in this part of my code:

```
    public Student this [int i]
    {
        get 
        {
            return students[i];
        }
        set
        {
            students[i] = value;
            Changed(this);
        }
    }
```

I'm sure the collection isn't getting updated correctly. Somewhere here:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValidData())
        {               
            List<string> result = txtScores.Text.Split(new [] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            student = new Student(txtName.Text, result.Select(int.Parse).ToList());
            this.Close();
        }

    }
```

The List Box is properly being filled but the index count is still 2 when it should be 3. What simple mistake did I make on the way?

Here's where student is supposed to be added to my collection:

```
    private void btnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewStudent addStudentForm = new AddNewStudent();
        Student student = addStudentForm.GetNewStudent();
        if (student != null)
        {
            students += student;
        }
    }
```

I get the feeling that this code is deigned to already have the student object complete at the time of the button click.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

I'm choosing index[3] from my list, but there's only two objects still. I'm not properly adding the new object to my list.

Comment: Somewhere I need to put in a students.Add, I'm searching but I'm running out of brain cells.

Comment: @user3390729 if you want to update you don't need add.you need to modify a student and fill your listbox with new records. But I don't see how do you pass your student instance to your second form? you are passing index as far as I can see but then how do you use that index? where is the student defined in the second form? you need to show use update form constructor

Comment: private void btnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddNewStudent addStudentForm = new AddNewStudent();
            Student student = addStudentForm.GetNewStudent();
            if (student != null)
            {
                students += student;
            }
        }

Comment: Since I'm returning a new student object and adding it to my students collection via +=, it should be added correct?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are fixed length once they're declared. OutOfRangeException when trying to pull data from an array usually indicates that you are searching in an index that doesn't exist.

Instead of using an array, why not use a list? Then, you could use stuff like foreach.

But if you don't want to do that, you're going to have to find a way to update your array (redefine it to be bigger) so that it doesn't attempt to return data that's out of range. :)